# Custom name/type of document ID and performance

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to store a class that looks like this

```cs
public class Wsp{

     //mapped
     public ObjectId ObjId {get; set;}  // not called Id
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;} 

     //NOT mapped
     public string Size  {get; set;} 
     public List<string> Sit  {get; set;}
     ..... 
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Wsp>(map =>
        {
            map.MapProperty(p => p.Name);
            map.MapProperty(p => p.ID);
            //what to do with ObjId ??
        });
```

I want to store only 3 values in Wsp Document in mongoDb.

```
ObjId -> primary key
Id
Name
```

When I select object from DB i want these values to be populated.

Another question is if in another class can I use Guid property as a primary key ? Will performance be worst than with ObjectID ? Can mongo db generate Guid or I must provide unique guid before inserting ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want the attribute to control which field to map and which not to?

Comment: I don't want to be tied to mongoDB in my models. Next step for me will be removing ObjectID from models. I want them to be datasource independent.

Comment: Then don't you think you should have another layer to isolate your model and database? That would be the purpose of DTO, which represents database object and thus your model still represents your domain.

Comment: Any good instructions on DTO mongoDb in C# ? Is there a way to do this my way ? With RegisterClassMap ?

Comment: DTO is not MongoDB specific, but that's another topic. With RegisterClassMap, if ID is the only problem, then yes. I think [MapIdField](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/2dcca712-765a-833d-87e9-8cb60acbe0e7.htm) is what you are looking for. You may also be interested in [API document of BsonClassMap](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/18aadb76-2494-c732-9768-bc9f41597801.htm)

Comment: a little bit explanation of DTO. If you want to isolate database from your project, it's far more complex than this. but basically you should have a DAL(Data access layer) to provide all database accessing functions, and DTO to map the data. Thus when database changes you just change the DAL logic and the way how you map to DTO (I use AutoMapper to do this). In one word, to isolate database is not what you can do easily. And in most situations it's not necessary.

Comment: @yaoxing thanks you for your answers I will try tomorrow to use MapIdField, DTO is a task for future :)

Comment: @yaoxing when I use MapIdField the id in database is not autogenerated, always 00000000000.....  Why it is so hard to do such simple thing. I only want to have access to Id of the object from DB in C# code nothing else.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the ID is actually generated by the driver, not by the database. Now that you are mapping it by yourself, I guess you're on your own to generate the ID (I agree the driver should have done the job though). Provide an `ObjectId` with `ObjectId.GenerateId()` would do the job. for performance reasons the ID is generated by client side (otherwise you'll have to go to server again to retrieve server generated ID).

Comment: Seriously I'm surprised. I only want to save the ID generated by the driver to the `MyCustomIdName` and it can't be done automatic...   Do I have 100000% certainty that when I use `ObjectId.GenerateId()` on the C# site it will NEVER collide with Id's already stored in DB ???

Comment: Yes it's generated according to some principles which would avoid duplication. Include MAC/Machine/IP/timestamp whatever, I can't remember. It's designed for distributed environment, so don't worry about ObjectID.

Comment: Ok. I also found something like this `g.SetIdMember(g.GetMemberMap(x => x.Id));` I failed to use this with CustomIdName but maybe you have some idea about using it ? I don't understand why Custom Id Name causes problem in every example on the web...

Comment: I rarely use these methods, because I always isolate business model and database model. So I can simply add attributes to my database model. So, sorry I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question, just add [BsonId](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#identifying-the-id-field-or-property) like:

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId ObjId {get; set;}  // not called Id
```

Which indicates that this filed is primary key and should be mapped to _id field.

Basically you can use anything as ID, there's no limitation you must use some specified type. Thus you can use int/GUID/string, anything, as long as they are unique. You must provide ID if you expect it to be anything other than ObjectId.  Actually ObjectId is generated by driver, not by MongoDB.

**EDIT:** When you are using `BsonClassMap`, try the following

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Wsp>(map => 
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.MapProperty(p => p.Name);
    map.MapProperty(p => p.ID);
});
```

The [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#conventions) explained it clearly:

> For each convention there is a default convention that is the most likely one you will be using, but you can override individual conventions (and even write your own) as necessary.

Comment: You can also set the id explicitly yourself: ObjId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

Comment: This is not working. I have 
`BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Wsp>(map =>
            {
                map.MapProperty(p => p.Name);
                map.MapProperty(p => p.ID);

            });` how to add ObjId into mapping ?

Comment: dude, you should have mentioned it in your question.

Comment: But if I remember this Automap will map all my properties from model to database? I want only have Id, Name and ObjId stored in mongoDB.

Comment: Could you show me the whole dto and tell me which fields do you want to map which you don't. As well as the target name of these fields? Usually we prefer the attribute way to control it. It's easier and simpler.